# Enabling Delphi XE projects to run in earlier versions - uses naming & project options

Tags: delphi

could anyone remind me what is the trick to allow earlier versions of Delphi (2010 for example) to accept units written in later versions which have the domain.sub-domain naming system like

```
    // Delphi XE2 & later version (comment out for 2010 & earlier):
      uses
        Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,system.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
        Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons,
        Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, System.Math;
```

as opposed to the D2010 & earlier convention

```
    // Delphi 2010 & earlier version (comment out for XE2 & later):
      uses
        Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics,
        Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls, Buttons, ExtCtrls, ComCtrls, Math;
```

I know there's something you can do in project>options but can't find it & haven't been able to find earlier forum posts on the subject..

Comment: To make your code compatible you should avoid using `Ugly.Unit.Naming` and configure `-NS` option for the newer compilers.

Comment: @FreeConsulting That works up to a point. If your code needs units from namespaces that have clashing unit names you are in trouble. For example you write an FMX project that uses a couple of VCL units. Unusual to do so I know, but not unheard of. Forcing the use of `-NS` passes the buck to the consumer of the library and makes it harder for them to simply absorb code. For that reason I think most 3rd party vendors use conditional compilation. What would be useful would be local name space aliases, that could be applied in code and impact just the unit in which they appear.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, intermixing FMX and VCL already means trouble, no things are simple beyond this point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot do that. Versions of Delphi that pre-date unit scope names cannot understand them. The standard mechanism to write single source code for Delphi versions that span the unit scope names change is to use conditional compilation.

What is available is a compatibility tool in the other direction. The name space alias features allows newer versions to understand uses clauses that omit unit scope names.

Comment: David, rapid and detailed answer as ever! don't suppose you need any coding work?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Could you show an example of using conditional compilation in this context ?

Comment: The one liner example David put in his comment doesn't seem to work.   This is an example from the JCL    
{$IFDEF HAS_UNITSCOPE}
System.Types, Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils, Vcl.Graphics,
{$ELSE ~HAS_UNITSCOPE}
Types, Windows, SysUtils, Graphics,
{$ENDIF ~HAS_UNITSCOPE}

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I get [dcc64 Error] dx_RTTI.pas(10): E2029 Identifier expected but end of file found.  (Win64/Delphi 10 Seattle and Win32/XE7)

Comment: Not much to get wrong.., even tried with a known compiler define (to exclude the custom define):  {$IFDEF DEBUG}Vcl.{$ENDIF}StdCtrls

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What versions are supported by the one-liner?  I can't find a single one that works as you suggest.  Older versions, like Delphi5, certainly compile, but that's because the "Vcl." portion isn't referenced. Anything >= XE2 fails.  I'd assume that's why JCL uses separate lines as I put in my comment.

Comment: @Darian You are right. Sorry. I thought that it would be two identifiers, but `Vcl.StdCtrls` is one identifier in the eyes of the parser.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thanks for confirming... I tried multiple versions and couldn't get it to work.  I'd certainly PREFER it to work as you suggested.